# How to protect against mongo like SQL injection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been reading up on ways to protect against 'mongo injection' in my express backend. I typically use the package express-validator to sanitize and validate my inputs.

For example:

```
{"username": {"$ne": null}} //possible injection

.check('username').isString() //simple validation
```

Do you just verify the value is a string?

From what I understand the solution is to make sure "$" are not allowed or removed in the keys of JSON payloads passed to my endpoints. How do others protect against this?  Is there a way to go through the whole POSTed payload and remove any key value pairs that contain a "$" in the key? Just curious if I'm missing something obvious.